# how can the current flow if the potential difference is 0 volts?

Tags: voltage, transistors

I have read so many articles on so many websites about transistors and everywhere it says that when transistor is acting as a closed switch and conducting the voltage across collector-emitter is **0 volts**, so how can the current flow if the applied voltage across two points is 0 volts?
[image]

Comment: Be sure to read on the difference between npn and pnp transistors

Comment: james, the BJT as a switch has Vce acting like a small voltage source. The BJT in active mode (analog, if you prefer) has the collector acting like a current source. Your example schematic isn't with the BJT as a switch, but instead in active mode and working in analog fashion. I think it's a terrible schematic and could be improved for readability (to my mind.) Regardless, the emitter and collector are not close to each other in voltage. They are separated by at least a few volts, by design. Otherwise this schematic doesn't work well. You are supposed to assume an intelligent designer here.

Comment: If this was not possible, how could current flow through a wire? Voltage across a wire is always zero (assuming perfect wire, but whatever), but somehow, you easily accept that there can be current flowing through them, don't you?

Comment: Better be asking about superconductor, transistor drop voltage is not zero.

Comment: I can't believe this question about 0/0 is repeating over and over again in this platform.

Comment: @dim the collector and base junction is reverse biased so there needs to be some resistance and there is a battery connected to the collector-base junction shouldn't that count to give us some amount of voltage drop, I mean what if I connect a 20V battery in the collector and base junction

Comment: @james Nothing looks reverse biased to me at a first glance, but what do I know? Values of Vin, Vbe, Vbc are not specified, so it may be reverse biased, or it may not. In any case, a potential of 0 volts between emitter and collector is just normal for a saturated transistor, and of course it allows current to flow. That's actually thanks to this 0 volt potential that current flow can be maximized: the transistor then behaves just like a wire. If you have a voltage between E and C, then it *prevents* some current to flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those situations where "ideal model" and "real physical system" differ; all real physical conductors (except superconductors, which are weird) have ohmic properties and a non-zero resistance. So the voltage won't be zero, it'll be *nearly* zero.

Educational models and many simulators round "nearly zero" to zero to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 2):

In reality the voltage difference will seldom be zero.  If the transistor is switched fully on then the voltage drop will be small (much less than 1 volt).  To say that it’s zero is an over-simplification

Answer (score 2):

If the voltage is zero and the resistance is zero then: -

$$\text{Current} = \dfrac{0}{0}$$

In other words, you cannot determine what current is flowing by simple ohm's law.

Think about a pure inductor; you apply a voltage across it and current ramps up at a rate of: -

$$\dfrac{V}{L} \hspace{1cm}\text{amps per second}$$

After a short time you disconnect the voltage and instantly apply a short across the pure inductor. Current continues to flow indefinitely. It's not magic.

> *everywhere it says that when transistor is acting as a closed switch
> and conducting the voltage across collector-emitter is 0 volts*

Everywhere you have read that is either incorrect or, you have misread that information because it's a physical impossibility.

Comment: And of course if a particular wire is a .001ohm resistor, and has .01V across it, that's a 10amp current.   "Zero ohms" is the key to understanding.  "Zero ohms" gives all conductors the strange ability to support "zero volt" currents.  (Or in other words, OTHER resistors in series are determining the current in a switched-on transistor, since the zero-ohm transistor, like any piece of wire, would short-out a normal power supply voltage-source.)